# How can I get Map<String, Records> from Map<String, List<Records>>

Tags: java

This is code I have tried:

```
Map<LocalDate, List<Records>> outputs = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, List<Records>> prevDateData = outputs.get(currentDate.minusDays(1))
                                .stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Records::getId));
```

But I want to achieve data structure from outputs:

```
Map<String, Records> prevDateData
```

Can someone suggest how I could do that?

Comment: That only makes sense if you have a single record in each list

Comment: You probably can't. Assuming you have a list of records for each key in your map, you won't be able to store these in a flattened map, as you cannot have duplicate keys. This would mean you can only store a single record for each key.

Comment: You want to reduce the list to a single element. But you need to explain the rules for this reduction, otherwise probably you won't be able go get much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preserve all `Records` from the list, some logic for apply some logic resolving `Records` mapped to the same key needs to be applied. For instance, keep the one that has the latest timestamp, otherwise it wouldn't be possible.

That's how it can be done using using three-args flavor of Collector [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)):

```
Map<String, List<Records>> prevDateData = outputs.get(currentDate.minusDays(1))
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Records::getId,      // keyMapper
        Function.identity(), // valueMapper
        (left, right) -> *your logic for resolving duplicates here* // mergeFunction
    ));
```

The simplest example `mergeFunction` would be `(l, r) -> r` which overrides the previously associated value with a new one. You might want something more elaborate.

Merge function is of type `BinaryOperator`, and static methods [`minBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html#minBy(java.util.Comparator)) and [`maxBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html#maxBy(java.util.Comparator)) producing a `BinaryOperator` based on the provided Comparator might be helpful in implementing the merge function.